# Exporting Excel sheet as PDF with data coming from Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm kinda new to VBA. I have an Excel file with several sheets and i need to export in PDF the first sheet.

The first sheet contains three charts whose data changes when I enter a numeric code in a cell and select the only value that comes out in another cell where the Data Validation is set.

Since there are about 200 PDFs to generate, I'd like to avoid the manual work of copying/pasting the numeric code and selecting the value from the dropdown menu and then exporting the sheet in PDF for 200, but with as few clicks as possible. Can this procedure be automated with a macro?

Thanks for every help and tip!

Comment: Yes this can most likely be automated. You may want to see [ask] and [reprex] though.

Comment: Record a macro while performing a couple of exports, then use that as a starting point.